# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flickrConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have prob with api flickr in spring boot project.

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flickrConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'flickr.apiKey' in value "${flickr.apiKey}"
```

FlickConfiguration.java

```
package com.gaaloul.gestiondestock.config;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.REST;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.auth.Auth;
import com.github.scribejava.apis.FlickrApi;
import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1AccessToken;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1RequestToken;
import com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth10aService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@Configuration
public class FlickrConfiguration{
    @Value("${flickr.apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${flickr.apiSecret}")
    private String apiSecret;

    @Bean
    public Flickr getFlickr() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, FlickrException {
        Flickr flickr = new Flickr(apiKey, apiSecret, new REST());

        OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder(apiKey)
                .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                .build(FlickrApi.instance(FlickrApi.FlickrPerm.DELETE));

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final OAuth1RequestToken request = service.getRequestToken();
        final String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(request);
        System.out.println(authUrl);
        System.out.println("Past it here >>");

        final String authVerifier = scanner.nextLine();
        OAuth1AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(request,authVerifier);
        System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());
        System.out.println(accessToken.getTokenSecret());

        Auth auth =flickr.getAuthInterface().checkToken(accessToken);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(auth.getToken());
        System.out.println(auth.getTokenSecret());

        return flickr;
    }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
      datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        username: root
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionstock?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
        password:
      jpa:
        database: MYSQL
        generate-ddl: 'true'
        properties:
          hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        show-sql: 'false'
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
    
        server:
          port: 8081
    
        flickr:
          apiKey : ffb5dde7ae207966c25094d50c735374
          apiSecret: 1a680974316268ff
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gaaloul</groupId>
    <artifactId>gestiondestock</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Gestion de stock</name>
    <description>api REST du projet gestion de stock</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            -<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flickr4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>flickr4java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I tried to salvage your question as it was poorly formatted. Please fix the formatting in your yaml file as I don't know what the actual layout is. Remove the `hibernate` dependencies those are incompatible (hibernate 6 is JakartaEE not JavaEE) and are already provided by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: If you want those 2 keys to work, `flickr` should not be indented (be on the left of the file without space before it)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've only been using application.properties file so far, so I'm not too sure about the YAML syntax, but from the key structure I see in your YAML, any chance that the value should instead be supplied as spring.jpa.flickr.apiKey and spring.jpa.flickr.apiSecret, instead of flickr.apiKey and flickr.apiSecret?

Comment: please consider posting this as a comment, answers should be definite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by generating new key and secret

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).